# Define some generics, infer the rest

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code. I have declared a `Component` constant which infer the generic types as I would expect. However, I want to be able to extend the prop type of the component (*see `ComponentWithExtraProp`*) but as soon as I declare one of the type generics it seems like Typescript opts out of type inference with the error:

> Expected 4 type arguments

So it seems like I'm in a situation where I either have to declare all type generics explicitly or infer all type generics. Is there anyway to declare **only one** *(or some)* of them, while inferring the rest?

```js
export const withStaticProps = <
  Props,
  Context,
  StaticProps,
  Component extends (props: Props & StaticProps) => string,
>(
  getStaticProps: (context: Context) => Promise<{ props: StaticProps }>,
  component: Component,
): Component & {
  getStaticProps: (context: Context) => Promise<{ props: StaticProps }>;
} => {
  return Object.assign(component, { getStaticProps });
};

const Component = withStaticProps(
  async ({ bar }: { bar: string }) => Promise.resolve({ props: { foo: bar } }),
  (props) => `Foo: ${props.foo}`, // Foo: astring
);

Component.getStaticProps({ bar: "astring" }).then((res) => {
  console.log(res.props.foo); // "astring"
});


const ComponentWithExtraProp = withStaticProps<{ extra: string }>( // Expected 4 type arguments, but got 1.
  async ({ bar }: { bar: string }) => Promise.resolve({ props: { foo: bar } }),
  (props) => `Foo: ${props.extra}`, // Property 'extra' does not exist on type 'Props & StaticProps'.
);

ComponentWithExtraProp.getStaticProps({ bar: "astring" }).then((res) => {
  console.log(res.props.foo); // 'res.props' is of type 'unknown'.
});
```

Link to [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wO4EsYAsDKMAhjFggApQRipwC8cAPAFBxyXWoA0rcAwihigYPNoRJkONUfwgBbSMmDJ4w5QBNaACjBUaALnZ7aAMjjjSFYwEp6APjjooWZAHMedrb1fAYFycaGWkgqwoYCoSAwtnQOHHJYqMCMAN5wupyG-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-nA6gQMGcDINOlYgIk8AoN2vbAH+MxmGaNC-vOiapg8MCZnguZagWegmm0pYdBaG4xlu9qOs6txBqgHorIgKAUpSvr+oG5KnKGsoRlGv6cVKgGJHAEDMnBfa-usyAANbgRgyBoQmfxAA)

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't currently possible in TS; see the linked question and answer for details.  One common workaround is to use currying as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/m3BnLN).